# Optimize Switch case PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, switch-statement

I am currently creating a website in wordpress, and we have a 3 level navigation structure. The first two are always visible, but the third is dependent on the page you are currently visiting. Which means it has to switch.

For that, a switch statement would work, but considering we have a lot of different subpages, the amount of code will be quite big.

We have a template code, that will work for each menu (as it uses the same styling and placement), so all we really need is to switch out which template it's refering too.

We are currently determining the condition on is_page() like so:

```
if ( is_page() ) { // only do this for actual pages
         $page_obj = get_queried_object();

         switch ( $page_obj->post_name ) {

                case "products":
                    echo '<div class="third_menu_over">';
                    echo '<div class="container">';
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'products',
                    'menu' => 'products_menu',
                    'depth' => 0,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'third_menu',
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
                    ));
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                break;
```

Comment: So I guess the question is, "How do I do this smarter" ?

Comment: put each of the cases into a separate method and call that in the switch statement instead - or even better, use a single method (that can be even used from each of those separate new methods) and let it contain the start + end of your HTML, co you don't write a lot of duplicate code

Comment: Use parent / active classes to hide/show the 3rd level

Comment: another approach would be to think on which pages/posts you _don't_ want to display the 3rd menu and use a negative condition. Try to think of some sort of grouping logic for the posts that need to display or not display the 3rd menu, you can add a custom field, ex `display3rdmenu=true` and test against this field/value.